# Test if reduction of coefficient of variation is significant

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I have the following problem:

I want to compare two different quantification processes and I use the coefficient of variation as quality metric. So in principle my data look like:

experiment method1 method2

1            a11     a12

2            a21     a22

3            a31     a32

and so on

method 2 gives a lower CoV (standard deviation / mean). However the question is: is it statistically significant?

Comment: @MachineLearner see edit

Answer (score 1):

If the coefficient of variation is defined by $$\text{CV}=\dfrac{\sqrt{\text{Var}[X]}}{\mathbb{E}[X]}.$$

If you estimate the coefficient of variation by $\hat{\text{CV}}=s/\bar{x}$. You can use the following confidence intervals $\text{CI}$ to see if all coefficients lie inside the [same confidence interval (hence, no change)](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/6354/3d325915e92a08de16463dd918caf9d5a2bf.pdf).

$$\text{CI}:\hat{\text{CV}}\pm z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\hat{\text{CV}}^4+0.5\hat{\text{CV}}^2}{N}}.$$

In which $N$ is the sample size.